# When did the trans-Jordanian territories acquire kedusha?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu, mattos

Two-and-a-half tribes (Reuben, Gad and half of Menasseh) had land on "the other side" of the Jordan river, allocated to them by Moses in Bemidbar 32, and made conditional on their participation in the conquest of the rest.

At what point did that land become part of the land of Israel? Was it immediate? Or was it only once the rest of the land had been conquered and was ready to be parceled out to the other tribal leaders?

I am asking because I want to know the status of the land on which Moses stood *at the time that he was standing on it*. Did Moses get to "enter" the land of Israel, or didn't he? The text says that he didn't, but he *was* standing on ground that we consider part of the land of Israel.

Comment: "that we consider part of the land of Israel" I don't think that's true. Why do you think it ever became part of the land of Israel? For instance, there's no shmitta over there nor biblical tithes.

Comment: @ShimonbM I am curious to know if the answer below satisfied your question?

Comment: @mbloch Respectfully, no... I appreciate that those tribes didn’t gain possession of their land until a certain time had elapsed, but want to know whether the land itself was sacred. The territory of Judah, for example, or Dan didn’t pass to those tribes until they conquered them either, but they were certainly already part of “the land” itself before then.

Comment: @ShimonbM first of all feedback is great - takes time to answer questions so want to make sure it helps. If it doesn't then happy to think further. This being said the core of your question text is "At what point did that land become part of the land of Israel?" which I tried to answer. But it feels now what you really want to know is when the land became sacred? Isn't that after Joshua's conquest? See details of the areas in [MT Terumot 1:2 and ff](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/992027/jewish/Terumot-Chapter-1.htm) - is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @mbloch - I’ll give you a +1 if you like. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, I just don’t think you did. All you’ve done is show me that those regions didn’t become the property of those tribes until after the conquest, but that’s an open verse. It’s not really what I’m asking. None of the land became the property of *any* of the tribes until after the conquest!

Comment: @ShimonbM I thank you for the +1 but what I like even more is to answer questions correctly :-> If I didn't answer your question to your satisfaction, and no one else did, maybe you could further refine your question. If you are asking about the kedusha of the land, is there a question or is it clear this is after Joshua's conquest. And if not that, and not my answer, then what you are asking? I'm not challenging, just genuinely trying to understand

Comment: @DoubleAA would be interesting to clarify your first comment above since I've been thinking about it ever since you wrote (and relooked at Mishna Bikkurim over shabbat). My understanding is that (1) Ever HaYarden is part of Eretz Israel (not part of the land of the seven tribes originally promised to Avraham but part of the 10 tribes), (2) that it was sanctified by Yoshua then Ezra and (3) that truma, maaser, shviit, orlah, kilayim apply there (it says so explicitly in my commentary to Bikurim 1:10). I'm not challenging or attacking, not trying to learn this right.

Comment: '@mbloch Isn't that all Derabanan? Terumot and Maaserot even apply in Bavel, Amon and Moav MiDerabanan. (I did say 'biblical') It's certainly possible there is/was machloket about this, but the OP's position is by no means obvious.

Comment: @DoubleAA that is not my understanding. See [MT Trumot 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Heave_Offerings.1.2?lang=bi) and last para before bibliography [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/terumot-and-ma-aserot). But I might be wrong, I'm trying to understand

Comment: @mbloch עבר הירדן, שביעית נוהגת בה מדבריהם. http://mechon-mamre.org/i/7704.htm#25

Comment: @DoubleAA see notes 91 and 92 [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007165/jewish/Shemita-Chapter-4.htm#footnote91a1007165) - could it be we are speaking of two different time periods. Originally it was d'oraita, after the exile of Reuven/Gad it became d'rabanan?

Comment: @mbloch Anything is possible. It's also possible that while Reuven/Gad need to be settled in their plots for Yovel to be in effect, the rules didn't apply there. The point is the question should be asking what before when.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is only after the rest of the land was conquered but before the land was allocated, and all this happened after the death of Moshe.

See [Bamidbar 32:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.32.29?lang=bi&aliyot=0) where Moshe instructs Eleazar and Joshua to give the land

> Moses said to them [Eleazar and Joshua], “**If** every shock-fighter among the Gadites and the
>   Reubenites crosses the Jordan with you to do battle, at the instance
>   of the LORD, **and** the land is subdued before you, **you** shall give them
>   the land of Gilead as a holding. But if they do not cross over with
>   you as shock-troops, they shall receive holdings among you in the land
>   of Canaan.”

Artscroll quotes Abarbanel that, although Gad and Reuven were ready to stay in Israel "mainland" until it was allocated to individual Jews, Moshe declined the offer and said that they need remain only until the wars were over (which took seven years) but before the other seven years for the allocation of land).

From the language in [Joshua 13:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.13.8?lang=bi) and following (e.g., [13:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.13.15?lang=bi)), it appears that Moshe assigned the land that was promised to them, it was then occupied by women and children but it became their formal possession only after the wars. Indeed I have now seen that [artscroll](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193318.html) on these verses quotes Lev Aharon: "**the tribes on the east bank did not acquire full ownership of their territories until Eretz Israel proper was in Jewish hands**. See also [Joshua 22](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.22.1?lang=bi).

---

On the question raised in comments of whether these territories were part of Eretz Israel, the gemara in [Arachin 32b](https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.32b.49?lang=bi) mentions that when the tribe of Reuven, Gad and half of Menasheh was exiled, the Yovels were suspended (since they apply only wen every one of the 12 tribes is settled in Eretz Israel in their respective places) which I think proves these tribe territories were in Eretz Israel (see [here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=173&article=605) for further discussion).

Comment: "Thus it was not until Joshua apportioned the land that the 2.5 tribes assumed title to their inheritance". A nuance that may need to be clarified - Moshe requested that the tribes just fight with the rest of them. The tribes volunteered to remain until the land was fully apportioned. I.e., they volunteered and did **more** than requested. That questions whether the land was theirs immediately after the wars were won (I.e., Moshe's request) or after they fulfilled what they volunteered to do. Refer to the verse that you cited.

Comment: @DanF I agree with all you write - my first sentence is indeed the land became theirs after the wars ended and before the land was fully apportioned. I meant to replace the sentence you quote by the one before - but forgot. I will remove it now with thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

The Netziv in Haamak Davar on this passuk, (Bamidbar 33:51) says

> כי אתם עוברים את הירדן וגו׳. אבל כ״ז שלא עברו את הירדן לא״י לא הוזהרו להאביד ע״ז בעה״י. דאזהרה זו היא משום קדושת הארץ. ואין עה״י מתקדש אלא אחר שנתקדש א״י כמו לענין ערי מקלט שאינן קולטות עד שיהיו נגמר גם בא״י משום דערי מקלט תלוי בקדושת הארץ בזמן שהיובל נוהג. ויובל תלוי בזמן שכל ישראל על אדמתם וע׳ להלן ל״ה י׳ ומש״ה לא הוזהרו לבער ע״ז מעה״י עד שיטהרו מא״י:

> When you cross. As long as they had not yet crossed the Yardein into Eretz Yisroel, they were not ordered to destroy the idol worship on the other side of the Yardein. This commandment depended on the holiness of the Land of Israel; the other side of the Yardein did not become sanctified until Eretz Yisroel was sanctified. This is similar to the concept of the Cities of Refuge that did not take in accidental murderers until those in Eretz Yisroel would also be sanctified, because the activation of the Cities of Refuge depends on the holiness of Eretz Yisroel which in turn is only when the Jubilee year is being observed.